# USB drive 'NTFS' works on some Windows platforms but not others, very annoying

Tags: filesystems, windows, usb-drive

I have two USB-sticks, a newer 'blue' 3.0 one and older 2.0 one which are now and then used for different purposes, sometimes I may turn one into a Linux live USB to test some distro, other times I may turn them into more universally formatted ones when I need to hand someone the stick with some files or go to a print shop.

It never goes wrong with handing someone on a Windows PC the USB stick.

Sometimes it does with the printshops, which is something I do about once a month. Usually it can be remedied but today it took hours out of my day :(

So I took the USB-stick to a self-service kiosk with some kind of tablet which rejected the USB-stick saying it only accepts Windows formatted ones.

Then after a stress attack drove it many kilometres away and another shop opened my file without any issues whatsoever form a desktop Windows PC (most probably) and printed it.

Here is a command with output showing what there is to know about the filesystem on this :

```
$ sudo file -Ls /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 32, heads 64, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 32, sectors 30218841, $MFT start cluster 4, $MFTMirror start cluster 1888677, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number ------------
```

(removed the serial number, don't think it's necessary)

Is there anything here which indicates why it would work on one Windows system and not another?

So the one that refused it is possibly some kind of 'embedded' system, not sure what variant of Windows that may use.

Maybe Microsoft pushes some kind of "reject USB" bit with each update of Windows so as to cause Linux users the maximum annoyance. Then, Linux has to play catchup. Who knows :(

I'm running Debian Buster. Any tips on this or a more failsafe way to format a USB on Linux so it is more univeral would be great, save this from happening again.

Comment: Do you have a partition on the drive or did you format the entire disk to NTFS? Windows sometimes has a problem with such disks. New `dosfstools` even creates a fake partition table if you decide to format an unpartitioned disk to FAT (but I am not sure if this is a problem with NTFS too).

Comment: @VojtechTrefny it is one partition formatted to NTFS. Maybe some command out of that `dosfstools` will create a more reliable format than `gparted` gui which is what I typically use to format these sticks. A folder 'System Volume Information' seems to create itself and I sometimes delete it but don't think that is really the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of NTFS is 3.1, which has been the case since the release of Windows XP. [See Wikipedia for more details.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS).

If a self-service kiosk is based on a Windows version that pre-dates Windows XP, then it may fail to understand the current NTFS version. Most cameras don't use NTFS anyway: they tend to use FAT32 or ExFAT, and I would not be too surprised if the designers of the self-service kiosks mostly test those filesystem types only. ExFAT is even the "default" filesystem for SDXC cards according to the SD Association that maintains the memory card specification.

If the kiosks are Android-based or otherwise "Windows-free", they might not support NTFS at all, out of abundance of caution towards copyright and licensing issues.

You're probably using NTFS because FAT32's file-size limit of 4 GB can be an issue. ExFAT would also remove that limit. If your files are smaller than 4 GB, then FAT32 would probably be the most universally accepted filesystem.

The `mkntfs` man page of Debian 11's `ntfs-3g` package claims the tool will create NTFS filesystems that should be acceptable without errors by at least Windows Vista, 7 or 8. Other versions might produce a warning if the uppercase file (the file that defines the mapping between character cases for all Unicode characters supported by the filesystem in question) for that OS version is different from what Windows Vista, 7 or 8 had. As the man page says, this may happen because newer versions of Windows take into account new characters defined by the Unicode consortium. But if this causes a self-service kiosk to reject the USB media, a bug report to the kiosk system vendor would be very appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that is amazing detail. What a nightmare - I can see from the Wiki page that there have been only 5 releases of NTFS and that most recent one was 2001, so it hasn't changed for a long time. The kiosk operator is a massive company. Its error message mentioned Windows so possibly it is Windows not Android, question is if its _Windows version pre-dates Windows XP_ .

Comment: Importantly, if I read between the lines you are saying _FAT32 or ExFAT,_ are more universal (would save my nerves). When I use these sticks to hand a file to someone or go to a kiosk it is never something anywhere near 4GB let alone bigger than that - be lucky if it were bigger than 10MB! So it sounds like the answer is FAT32 from now on, nothing will ever reject it. Would that be right?

Comment: If you don't have files larger than 4 GB, then FAT32 is probably the most universally accepted filesystem.

Comment: I went back there with the stick formatted FAT32 with something I wanted to print and this time it loaded and printed without any issues. I think files read / write slower on this but they're small files anyway and it gives it a retro feel.